# How to check a div contain radiobutton or not in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Is there a way to check if a `<div>` contains a radio button or not using jquery and javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if($('div').find(':radio').length > 0){
 //stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) like this, You can learn more about selectors over [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

*Using id selector*

```
if($('#divID :radio').length)
{
   //
}
```

*Using class selector*

```
if($('.div-class :radio').length)
{
   //
}
```

*Using tag name selector*

```
if($('div :radio').length)
{
   //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').children('input[type="radio"]').length
```

This will return quantity of radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
if($('div').children('input:radio').length > 0){
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
if($('#yourDivId input:radio').length) {
  //its inside
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("div input").attr("type")=="radio")
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
if($("#divid:has(radio)");)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try,

```
if ($("div input:radio").length > 0){
  // do something here...
}
```

or else you can check whether it exists in following manner as well,

```
jQuery.fn.exists = function(){return this.length>0;}

if ($("div input:radio").exists()) {
    // Do something here....
}
```